# Ruby parse time zone string FORMAT for DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I am trying to parse a string that's hitting my api. The incoming string is

```
"2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z"
```

I need it in the following format for my db sql to work:

```
"2014-03-19 00:00:00 -0400"
```

Right now, the solution I have come up with is

```
Time.zone.parse("2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z").in_time_zone('America/New_York').to_s
```

This feels like an inelegant solution to me and I feel that there should be a more dynamic way of doing things without specifying the time zone name (it should be local by default). I just want to switch the formatting of the strings as they are supposed to be equivalent. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the [`time_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) in the `application.rb` file and use it as below:

```
# application.rb:
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'America/New_York'
end

Time.zone.parse("2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z").to_s
# => "2014-03-19 00:00:00 -0400"
```

More examples of use

```
$ > Time.zone = "America/New_York"
# => "America/New_York"
$ > Time.zone
# => (GMT-05:00) America/New_York 
$ > Time.zone.now
# => Sat, 22 Mar 2014 18:28:48 EDT -04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):008:0> Time.parse("2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z").getlocal.strftime("%F %T %z")
=> "2014-03-19 04:00:00 +0000"
```

On a system in GMT+1:

```
irb(main):003:0> Time.parse("2014-03-19T04:00:00.000Z").getlocal.strftime("%F %T %z") 
=> "2014-03-19 05:00:00 +0100"
```

Comment: this is its current format. I need the -0400 to be at the end

Comment: It is there. My locale timezone is UTC so +0000.

Comment: Added an example running on another of my servers in GMT+1